# How i can create a filter ONE term kw to Google Ads Campaigns?

Tags: looker-studio

I need to know how to make that filter

["Single word keywords in your account"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uaEFb.png)

I tried many options but I couldn't make this filter correctly.

If you know the answer or have any ideas, it's a good idea to get started.